# Not returning value in vue function

Tags: vue.js

I'm using vue and I'm trying to return a user's email. I have 2 separate functions and one gets all the products while the other one
is supposed to get the user emails that is attached to that product.

The issue I'm having is that the emails isn't showing up and I'm getting an undefined as well.

Here is my code

```
<template>
    <div class="card" style="width: 100%;">
        <div class="card-body">
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col">Email</th>
                        <th scope="col">Product</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="product in products">
                        <td>
                            {{ getProductUser(product.user_id) }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ product.action }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ product.options }}
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            {{ product.created_at }}
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props:['id', 'user', 'product'],
        data(){
            return {
                products: [],
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getProducts(){
                axios.get('/api/products/'+this.id+'/product').then(response => {
                    this.products = response.data.products;
                });
            },
            getProductUser(user){
                axios.get('/api/product/'+user).then(response => {
                    return response.data.email;
                });
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getProducts();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What does your "undefined" error say?

Comment: I'm getting a 500 error, my url looks like this `http://site.test/api/product/undefined`
and in my network tab it says `SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type bigint: "undefined" (SQL: select * from "users" where "id" = undefined and "users"."deleted_at" is null limit 1)"`

Comment: Seems like `product.user_id` is undefined, check what properties does `product` have, you either forgot to set an `user_id` or misspelled it

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact that `product.user_id` is undefined as stated in the comment, you have another issue.

`getProductUser` doesn't return an email. It returns a promise that will provide an email.

Simplest solution would be

```html
<td>
  {{ product.userEmail }}
</td>
```

(which is by the way an equivalent to `<td v-text="product.userEmail"/>`, vue templates can be much cleaner than standard HTML).

```js
  getProducts(){
    axios.get('/api/products/'+this.id+'/product').then(response => {
      this.products = response.data.products;

      this.products.forEach(product => {
        axios.get('/api/product/'+user).then(response => {
          product.userEmail = response.data.email;
        });
      })
    });
```

This should work, but keep in mind that **executing additional request per product is generally a bad idea**, the performance would be much better if `/api/products/{id}/product` would have `userEmail` property already initialized.